# How to sync oracle production database to development database

Tags: database, oracle, synchronization

Our production database is on Oracle and for a new project we really need a development server. We have set-up a server on azure but we would like an exact copy from time to time.

The current size of our database is about 60GB. This may not be a lot, but it's too mush to quickly copy to our development environment.

Options?

- Dump to SQL file, copy to dev and import. -> Might work.. but it might take a few days every time we like to sync.
- Thirth party tool such as [dbForge Data Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/datacompare/editions.html)

Any other options?

Comment: Is the other db also oracle?

Comment: Yes, both are on Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `MATERIALIZED VIEWS` (with `FAST REFRESH`), esp. when it is not necessary to copy/update each single table.

Another option it the "Oracle Data Guard" product, however there is a considerable price-tag on it.

Comment: Oracle Streams maybe?